# How to print Arabic characters using Xamarin.Forms, Inner printer built-in Sunmi V1s

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, printing, xamarin.android, arabic

I am trying to **print Arabic characters** using [Sunmi V1s](https://sunmi.com/en/V1s/).

I send the text to the printer but, it's print them incorrectly

like this image

[image]

Code:

```
var result = Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII").GetBytes("طباعة نص"); // Print Text

socket.OutputStream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
```

I tried various encode (UTF-8, UTF-7, UTF-32, ASCII, Unicode) but unfortunately, nothing works.

I wonder if the code missing something?

Comment: can you send me your particular area of code. So i can check the issue

Comment: @manoj I use the principle of [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Comment: the printer is recognizing the letters of the words but showing them as question marks. Could it be that the printer doesn't have any arabic font?